# How to write two theorems in a row in Lyx (or two of any AMS math environments) in a row

Tags: lyx

Lyx/Latex beginner here.

I'm using Lyx with an AMS article document class. I want to write a lemma with the text "text 1" followed by another lemma with the text "text 2". When I try to do this using the lemma environment from the Lyx environment menu in the top left, it acts as if (what I want to be) the second lemma is just a continuation of the first and doesn't create the second lemma environment. The only way I can get it to create the second lemma is by having something in between the two lemmas e.g. a line of Standard environment with a space in it (by pressing ctrl-space). But then that puts too much space in between the lemmas.

Is there a way to get two lemmas back-to-back without anything in between?

Thanks!

Here is the code from the lyx latex preview pane (the tilde is what I get from pressing ctrl-space):

```
\begin{lem}
text 1
\end{lem}

~
\begin{lem}
text 2
\end{lem}
```

[image: Two lemmas with a space in between]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your cursor somewhere in the first Lemma (doesn't need to be the first line). Then go to Insert > Separated Lemma Below. The keyboard shortcut for this (at least on Linux) is alt + p, return.